# Nodejs appear installed but "--version" is not working. On Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: sudo, nodejs, npm

I am having trouble in installing *nodejs*, *npm* and a specific version of *angularCli*.
THe problem is that *nodejs* appears installed when I use the command

`sudo apt install nodejs`

but appears not installed when I check for the version.
By using the command `which`, I am not finding any of *nodejs*, *npm* or *ng*

Like I am showing in the [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9wZM.png).

Comment: Providing your OS, release details, and source for the package may also help  (*the package in your provided picture; which should be pasted as text in your question doesn't match any supported release so clues on where it came from maybe required*)

Comment: I already tried, with command which nothing appear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the Node version at the default Apt PPA is broken. The package is no longer maintained and hasn't been for a while now. It is stuck at version 10, whereas the current official stable release is 17.X.XX. The version is so old that it will not work (trying to use via command line will just give a version deprecation warning), and the NPM configuration installs in a way that anything installed with `npm install xxxxx` will not be useable.

My advice is to uninstall via apt remove and reinstall via `curl` or `wget`, or else add the NodeSource PPAs to `sources.list` and install from there. See [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-20-04).

Be sure to uninstall the Ubuntu Repository package first. Otherwise, the system may give the Apt-installed binary priority.